# Does a manager ever warm up two pitchers with the same handedness?

Tags: baseball, coaching, pitching

When a manager comes out to the mound to signal to the bullpen, he will simply motion with his left or right hand, indicating the throwing hand of the pitcher he wants.

Have there ever been two of the same throwing pitchers (left- or right-handedness), and if so, how does the manager indicate which of these he wants when he signals to the pen?

Comment: Ever in the history of every baseball game played everywhere in the world, of course there have been examples of this.

Answer (score 1):

There have absolutely been instances of this. The manager pointing to the handedness of the pitcher he wants is more of a formality. Almost always, when it is the manager himself walking out to the mound, the pitcher's day is done. However, before he has walked out there, the dugout and the bullpen (through the use of the bullpen phones) know who is coming next. The manager points to the arm, perhaps after his short discussion with the pitcher on the mound, to let the bullpen know that the pitcher due up (who already knows he is coming in the game) should begin coming in from the bullpen.

In total, it is more tradition than anything.